# jquery validate conditional max

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form where there's an option group with the choice of entering a value in pounds or a percentage.

Following this I have an input box for the actual value or the percentage.

I want to use the validate functions in jquery to set a conditional maximum value (e.g.100) if the user chooses the percent option.

Is this possible - I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
sponsorValue: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    max: function(element) {
    if ($("#sponsorOption").val() == '2'){ return 100;}
                       }
        }
```

can anyone offer any help?

Comment: What are you getting as a result with the code above?

Comment: The required and digits parameters work ok but the max doesn't. used Chrome JS error checker and the code appears to be well formed i.e. no syntax errors

Answer (score 5):

I think I may have cracked it:

```
sponsorValue: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    max: function(value,element) {
        if ($("input[name='sponsorOption']:checked").val() == '2') return 100;
               }
    }
```

I used a single checkbox instead of the radios in the end but I may try and retest using the radios.

Comment: This works with the radios too - in fact it works better - more functional.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the html form radios are marked up:

```
<input name="sponsorOption" type="radio" value="1" /> <span class="stdTxt">Amount</span><br />
<input checked="checked" name="sponsorOption" type="radio" value="2" checked="checked"/> <span class="stdTxt">Percentage</span>
```

apologies for adding this as an answer my user wasn't set up yesterday.

Comment: I think I may need to make the ids sponsorOption1 and sponsorOption2

Comment: still bashing away at this. Have  tried a lot of different variations. The problem seems to be that when the radio option is changed it doesn't update the value of the max. I tried to simply change the values of the radio buttons to match the thresholds required - e.g. 100 : 20000 and just use the value of the max as $("input[name='sponsorOption']:checked").val() - this didn't work either it just takes the intial default 'checked' value. very frustrating this.